# How is Microenvironment strictly defined?

Tags: human-biology

I started to think this definition of Wikipedia:

> Microenvironment (biology), a small or relatively small usually
>   distinctly specialized and effectively isolated biophysical
>   environment (as of a nerve cell)

and I started to think which environments can be examples of its. 
Joints, synovial joints with capsule, hyaline cartilage in capsules, ...?
I would like to get more examples of environments so I can think better definition.

**What is Microenvironment?**

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the term microenvironment depends on the scale of the system that you're looking at. It's a sort of weasel word that loosely means "context" or "stuff in the immediate surroundings of the system of interest that has some kind of an effect on it". I've seen it used to describe everything from the chemical microenvironment of a cell (e.g. a hormone gradient) to the electrostatic microenvironment of a single amino acid residue in a protein (e.g. the field from nearby charged residues).

Conceptually it's similar to the "surroundings" in the "system and surroundings" framework from statistical physics.

Comment: What does it mean in Medicine? I have seen it been used with synovial joints like capsule in the syvovial joint.

Answer (score 1):

This term is also used in cancer. Cancer cells can go into dormancy.  This is what they used to call remission. No one knows what the trigger is for them to leave G0 and start dividing again. However factors in the microenvironment,  is negativity for Ki-67 (index of proliferation), estrogen positivity are both factors but there are many others.

Comment: Is there any energy spectrum classification of these events? For instance, in Fourier spectrum and/or time-frequency joint spectrum? - - It would be very interesting to know more about them in microenvironments. - - However, I have no idea if you can get any 1D signals in such environments.

Comment: Excellent answer overall; however, wondering if you could add some references :)